# Sqlalchemy mssql conversion error for different value then query parameters

Tags: python, sql-server, t-sql, sqlalchemy, odbc

I'm using sqlalchemy orm. I have updated my table (both in db and in the orm), by changing the row importance from "VARCHAR" to "TINYINT". For some reason, whenever i try to add a a row, it with 'critical' instead of the new numeric value.

'critical' was one of the previously used values, which i have replaced with TINYINT and now use enum. I have checked the whole source code, and there is not even a single use of the word 'critical'.

Even the paramaters in error stack are mismatched. It seems as if some old value got inserted. I've also tried running this on another machine just in case, same thing happened.

```
(pyodbc.DataError) ('22018', "[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'critical' to data type tinyint. (245) (SQLExecDirectW)")
[SQL: INSERT INTO fulladb.packages (id, version, rdate, importance, metadata, source_url, pkgdata) OUTPUT inserted.id VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('858D60AF-A5E9-43F1-B19A-2D9CD10C0115', '1.1.1', datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0), 0, '[]', 'http://www.quack.com', '{}')]
```

EDIT:
I tried running more queries in SQL Server Managment Studio. Whenever i run an insert query, where i insert a VARCHAR into [importance] column, it correctly states it cant convert the string i entered (prints the correct string in the error) into tinyint.

If i insert a TINYINT (correct) value, then it by default always says it can't convert VARCHAR string 'critical'. For some reason it ignores int and always defaults to VARCHAR.

EDIT2:
To clear any misunderstandings. Im doing this on an empty testing database, i dropped all the tables and created new ones. This wasn't done by update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your attempt to updated the schema in the DB was not successfully. Since 'critical' was one of the previously used values, the DB rejected the schema update because it doesn't know how to handle the conversion of a VARCHAR to a TINYINT. Please check the DB on the commandline or using some other tool to make sure that the schema has actually been updated.

Comment: Should elaborate. 'critical' was a column value, not a name, it was just one of the 10 values that occured. I checked the databse with sql server managment studio, the tables were updated.

Comment: Edit: running queries from manager also raised the error. If i add string, the error correctly shows the string i erronously inserted. If i use an int, it by default raises error that it cant convert 'critical'.

Comment: From sql server management studio, can you see 'critical' as one of the column values? Or were all the old VARCHAR values converted to a TINYINT with some sort of mapping?

Comment: There are no old values. I dropped all the old tables, then ran the updated create script.